# Upgrade Heroku Postgres DB plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to Heroku hosting and was hoping one of the experts on StackOverflow could help me.

I originally signed up for a basic free postgres DB for my heroku app, but recently I've hit the 10K row limit and would like to upgrade to the $9/month plan. However, I have absolutely no idea how to do so.Is it a relatively simple process? I feel dumb for having to ask this question.

When I log into heroku and click on my app, I see a list of add-ons for my app. When I click on the Postgres add-on, it takes me to a separate webpage but I don't see any options for upgrading my DB plan.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a document on Heroku's site for doing exactly this: [Upgrade Heroku postgres with pgbackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups).

In short, the steps are as follows:

- setup a new new basic database
- Prevent updates (set maintence mode on)
- Capture your backup
- Restore the backup to the new database
- promote your new database
- make your app active

These are also the same steps to follow if you decide to go to a production plan.

Answer (score 28):

In pratical ways you can do this to upgrade your postgres database plan:

1. `heroku config`

   ```
   // It will show current database URL
   HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL: postgres://xxxddxxdx:sfsdfsfs-SIT@ec2-107-20-220-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/xdfdsxdxxxx
   HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SILVER_URL: postgres://fasdfsad:dsfsdfdsafdsf@ec2-54-225-136-187.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/sdfasdfdasfds

   // Default database set
   DATABASE_URL:  postgres://fasdfsad:dsfsdfdsafdsf@ec2-54-225-136-187.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dsfsdf
   ```
2. **Create a new database** `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic` (but I recommend that you go in server resource section and click Edit Addon and add pgsql and change plan from Free to your required plan)
3. **Run these commands to prevent database updates:**
   `heroku maintenance:on` and `heroku ps:scale worker=0`
4. **Copy current db to new db**:
   `heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL --app prod-test`

   Note:

   ```
   DATABASE_URL = It is config veriable which point default current db
   HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL = This is config variable for which db I just created
   prod-test = It is my APP name
   ```
5. Promote new database (Make new db as default db)
   `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL`
6. Re-enable worker/dynos
   `heroku ps:scale worker=1` and `heroku maintenance:off`
7. remove old database
   `heroku addons:remove HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SILVER_URL`

Comment: This should be the selected answer.  The heroku documentation with pg:dump is silly in this specific case, thank you Dhiraj!  Saved me some time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a straight forward process. They have an article just for that [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups).